# Принцип слоговой графики

Tags: русская-графика

[image]
Задание: определите количество случаев соответствия слоговому принципу графики. Укажите случаи отступления от слогового принципа графики.

Comment: @elenaalisa, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось, либо предложите свой вариант ответа.

Comment: я распределила слова и выделила случаи жирным шрифтом

Comment: Т.е. Вам только проверить надо?   
Я далек от школьно-вузовских методичек, ограничение от отступления не совсем отличаю, но внешне похоже, что так.   
Сейчас кто-нибудь авторитетно скажет.
@Людмила, это к Вам, наверное.

Comment: Да, только проверить!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так поняла, что нужно проверить уже выполненное задание? Тогда первая колонка абсолютно верна, а дальше пошли вопросы. Почему **чащоба** у Вас написана через Е? это как раз исключение - ограничение действия слогового принципа: и ЧА, и ЩО-должно бы быть Я и Ё, но всегда мягкий Ч делает это излишним.В транскрипции здесь не нужно писать Я-такого звука нет, это буква, а звук [А].Транскрипция здесь ничего не объясняет.

```
   2.написание букв е и э,
```

но это касается только смягчающей буквы е после букв **парных по твердости-мягкости** согласных в тех случаях, когда они обозначают твердые согласные.
Буква е после букв, обозначающих твердые согласные (из числа парных), пишется во многих заимствованных словах как бы незаконно. Ср., например, /э/ после /т/: антенна, контейнер, партер, синтетика, термос, теннис, эстетика; после /д/: дельта, модель, деформация; после /н/: кашне, туннель; после /с/: шоссе; после /з/: шимпанзе; после /р/: реквием, тире. Вот это отступления, а чащоба здесь никаким боком - это ограничение(после мягкого должна быть буква Ё)

Остальное вроде бы верно.

Comment: район - тоже транскрипция не нужна, да там у Вас и мягкость после гласного откуда-то взялась

Comment: транскрипция в задание не входит.

Comment: Ну, в отдельных случаях её можно написать, если она что-то объясняет, только правильно, а здесь она просто не нужна, потому что объяснение должно быть через другую букву, а не звук.

Comment: В слове "чащоба" буква А после Ч обозначает не И с призвуком Э?

Comment: Конечно, я объясняла, что звука Я не бывает, безотносительно к данному слову,здесь вообще не нужны звуки, это же графика, а не фонетика